# Can you map the execution order of following expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Please also describe that why this statement is executing that way.

I'm confused because `<` operator has higher precedence in the statement below. After execution of the `x > 0` the execution should go for `&&` operator but it is not executing. So I'm confused about what  the execution order is and why it is executing in that way.

Thanks for your time!

The code is following:

```js
let x = 1;

x > 0 || alert() && "hii"
```

Comment: Check out [AST explorer](//astexplorer.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [operators precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table).

- `>` has a highest priority
- `&&` is the next one by priority
- `||` is the next one by priority

So expression is executed like:

```
(x > 0) || (alert() && "hii")
```

In this case `x > 0` is `true`. Because JavaScript `||` [short-circuits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation) if the first operand is truthy, the second operand will not be evaluated.

Its like:

```
fun1() || func2()
```

If the return value of `fun1()` is truthy, than `func2()` will not be executed at all.

Comment: But according to you, after < operator, && operator have higher precedence, so why || operator is executing after execution of the < operator.

Comment: As its explained in short-circuits link in my comment. If && has higher priority than || than means that grouping of operands would be as its explained here: (x > 0) || (alert() && "hii") but execution will go from left to the right side, so (x>0) is true, then we have || and because of short-circuits thats the end of execution.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Well, is there any tool to which can tell execution orders of expresions of js, as im a beginner, i will definately encounter more confusing expression like this.

Comment: The best way would be to experiment with the things. Make various complex scenarios and debug things (with console.log() or debugger;), then you will realise the things. Also you will see, in the future, that you will try to avoid all complex  conditions just because of these things (and readability) and you will write them simpler (not everything in a on row, but to split it etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the right side of the `||` because the left side is already truthy, so no matter what the right side would be, it couldn't change the outcome anyway (both `true || true` and `true || false` would evaluate to `true`). Therefore, nothing other than `x > 0` needs to be evaluated to get an unambiguous result, `alert() && "hii"` is skipped and the return value is `true` (the result of `x > 0`). (This is called short-circuiting or conditional evaluation.) See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#note_on_grouping_and_short-circuiting).

Answer (score 0):

If you tried this :

```
let x = 1;

x > 0 || alert() && false
```

The output would be `true`, this is because `&&` is executed before the `||` operator, `"hii"` is evaluated as true so this what confused you to think that there is something wrong, as `( true || alert() && true` will give the same result as `true || (alert() && true)`.